# BibLaTeX alphabetic style - Choose letters for authors manually

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use BibLaTeX with the citation style `alphabetic`. Sometimes, the abbreviation letters for my citation (e.g. [ABC20]) isn't appropriate for a specific case. For example, if I have a citation of "The Apache Software Foundation", then there will be the abbreviation "[The20]". Instead, I would like it to be e.g. "[Apa20]". Is there any way to achieve this? I am using XeLaTeX in combination with Biber.

**Update:**

I wrote a short working example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{example.bib}
@software{Lucene.2020,
    author = {{The Apache Software Foundation}},
    year = {2020},
    title = {{Apache Lucene Core}},
    version = {8.7.0}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,%
style=alphabetic,%
natbib=true,%
hyperref=true,%
minnames=1,%
maxnames=2]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefirst}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnameaffix}[1]{\textsc{#1}}

\addbibresource{example.bib}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua \parencite{Lucene.2020}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add a `shorthand` argument to your specific bibentries. For example `shorthand = {Apa20}` in the case you mentioned. Of course you will have to rerun biblatex.

Comment: @Nico This worked perfectly fine, thank you. I wrote earlier that this didn't work for me, but there was just a typo in my code.